# How to integrate Instagram pictures into a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using sliderPro Slider to make a slider, exactly like in [this examples page](http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/#example2), so the HTML code looks like below:

```
<div id="example2" class="slider-pro">
  <div class="sp-slides">
    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
      <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_large.jpg">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_medium.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_large.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="sp-caption">Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery init code is like below:

```
$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

       $( '#example2' ).sliderPro({
            width: '20%',
            height: 500,
            aspectRatio: 1.5,
            visibleSize: '100%',
            forceSize: 'fullWidth'
        });
```

Now I was given [this link](https://www.instagram.com/hox_creativeproductions/) and was told that the images from that page should display in the slide instead of the images I am using right now. That's an Instagram account, so how do I integrate Instagram into my slider?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) to request media data for that user account.
You will get a response in JSON which you can easily parse to extract the image urls for your slider.

If you perform a `GET` to the endpoint below with a valid `USER-ID` and `ACCESS-TOKEN` it will return the user's most recent media in JSON. [More here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users)

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Another way is to use the embed endpoint.

If you perform a `GET` on a url like below it will return media data about that `USER-ID` account in JSON. More here [Embedding For Developers](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding)

```
https://www.instagram.com/USER-ID/media/
```

Other options include using a javascript or jquery plugin that handles most of this stuff for you but I'm sure you would have googled it if you needed that.